# Asking about reschuduling a meeting: Which preposistion should I use?

Tags: prepositions

> Is there a problem WITH / ON / TO reschedule the meeting?

In this question, I don't know which is the correct preposition: Is it *with*, *on*, or *to*?

Answer (score 1):

***[have a problem with sth/sb](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-a-problem-with-sth-sb)*** is an idiomatic expression:.

​

> to find something or someone annoying or offensive:
>
> - *I have a real problem with people who use their mobile phones on the train.
>     She can smoke - I don't have a problem with that.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

So your sentence would be: "Is there a problem with rescheduling the meeting?"

Comment: Alternatively, if you start the sentence "Is _it_ a problem...," then you would want "to reschedule."

Answer (score -2):

To reschedule.
After with you need -ing ending.

Comment: "Is there a problem to reschedule the meeting" sounds very non-fluent to this native US English speaker.  "with rescheduling" is fine, though.